# Tried to sign in with firebase on flutter and catch the error when credentials does not match

Tags: firebase, flutter

`dynamic result` in this method should return a 'null' from the signInWithEmail method but returned a Future instead. Hence, it does not go to the if statement.

**Sign in class**

```
                            RaisedButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                              ),
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Text("Login"),
                              onPressed: () async {
                                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                  dynamic result = _auth.signInWithEmail(email, password);
                                  if(result == null){
                                    setState(() {
                                      error = 'Email and Password does not match';
                                    });
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ),
```

Here is the signInWithEmail method. I tried to print the something in the catch to make sure it runs, and it does and should have returned a 'null'

**Firebase sign-in method.**

```
  Future signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    try{
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return _firebaseUser(user);
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert future into simple value using then method. Following code clear your idea.

```
_auth.signInWithEmail(email, password).then((result){    
    if(result == null){
       setState(() {
          error = 'Email and Password does not match';
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 Future signInWithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((result) {
      print(result);
      return result;
   })
    .catchError((error) {
      print("Something went wrong: ${error.message}");
      return error.message;
    });
  }
```

Use the [`catchError`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/DelegatingFuture/catchError.html) (This is the asynchronous equivalent of a "catch" block.) to be able to handles errors emitted by this Future

Then inside `onPressed`, do the following:

```
 onPressed: () async {
     if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _auth.signInWithEmail(email, password).then((result) {
         if(result.user == null){
          setState(() {
              error = result;
            });
        }
     }
   }
```

Then since the method `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` returns a `Future<AuthResult>`, therefore check if [`result.user`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/auth_result.dart#L18) is equal to null and assign the `result(error.message)` to the `error` variable.